# Determining complexity for functions (Big O notation)

Tags: c++, recursion, big-o

I've had this question in my midterm and I'm not sure of my answer, which was O(n^2) I want the answer with explanation , thank you .

```
int recursiveFun1(int n)
{  for(i=0;i<n;i+=1) 
      do something;                                                                 
    if (n <= 0)
    return 1;
else
    return 1 + recursiveFun1(n-1);}
```

Comment: Nopy, first your approach. And "I want the answer with explanation" sounds rude. Watch your language.

Comment: Your title says “Big O” but in your text, you are using a lower-case “o”. Note that [these mean different things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations), so please be precise. Also, `do` is a keyword in C++ introducing a loop. It would be clearer if you'd write `do_something()` instead.

Comment: Impressive how you were even too lazy to sensibly format the code.

Comment: The answer is O(n^2) **unless** the `something` in `do something` is not O(1).

Answer (score 3):

First I put your code with another indentation

```
int recursiveFun1(int n)
{  
  for(i=0;i<n;i+=1) // this is bounded by O(n)
    do something; // I assume this part is O(1)

  if (n <= 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return 1 + recursiveFun1(n-1);
}
```

The first thing to say is that each time `recursiveFun1()` is called `O(n)` is payed due to the `for`. Although `n` decreases at each call, the time is still bounded by `O(n)`.

The second thing is to count how many times `recursiveFun1()` would be called. Clearly (for me) it will be called exactly `n + 1` times, until the parameter `n` reaches the zero value.

So the time is `n + (n-1) + (n - 2) + ... + 1 + 0` which is `((n+1)n)/2` which is `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 2):

Denote by `R(n)` the execution time of this recursive function for input `n`. Then, if `n` is greater than 0, it does the following:

- `n` times `do something` - assuming the "something" has constant runnning time, it consumes `c1*n` time
- Various checks and bookkeeping work - constant time `c2`
- Calculating for input `n-1` - once. The running time of this is `R(n-1)` (by definition)

So

```
R(n) = c1*n + c2 + R(n-1)
```

This equation has a solution, which is `O(n^2)`. You can prove it by induction, or just by guessing a solution in the form `a*n^2 + b*n + c`.

Note: I assumed that "do something" has constant run time. This seems reasonable. However, if it's not true (e.g. it contains a recursive call), your complexity is going to be greater - maybe much greater, depending on what the "something" is doing.

Comment: this recursion reminds me of a double nested for loop, anyway you can verify that indeed it is O(n^2) by drawing the recursion tree, or you can just say that the function does linear work and its called n times which leads to o(n^2) . Great answer, upvoted.